# Error “URL de origen no admitida”

Tags: javascript, reactjs, img

Me encuentro trabajando en una aplicación con react js y en la misma tengo un formulario con input de imagen, al subirla imagen se almacena en el servicio de cloudinary pero resulta que este proceso no lo puedo completar ya que esa acción me devuelve los siguiente

```
 POST https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/CLOUDNAME/image/upload 400 (Bad Request)
error: {message: "Unsupported source URL: C:\fakepath\237959 (1).jpg"}
```

dejo la función

```
function SubmitImgTest(img){
const upload_preset = "***";
const formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append('file',img );
formdata.append('upload_preset', upload_preset);
const options = {
   method: "POST",
   body: formdata,
  };
fetch('https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/******/image/upload',options )
.then(res => res.json())
.then (datos => console.log(datos))
}
export default SubmitImgTest;
```

Comment: ¿Qué pasas por `img`?

Comment: en img recibo una imagen que es la quiero almacenar en el servicio de cloudinary

Comment: Te sucede con todas las imagenes o solo con esa en particular ?

Comment: con todas  las que ,subo ya que la subo todas desde mi directorio (porque estoy testeando), la ruta de todas las imágenes que envio serian asi: 'C:\Users\Usuario\Downloads\imagenejemplo.png'

Comment: No será que "img" es un string de la URL del archivo... y no el archivo como tal? porque lo que se debe incluir en la subida es el archivo, no la URL, porque la URL local no sirve para nada (o sea, esa fakepath). `img` debe ser es el archivo como tal, no solo su URL

Comment: @xentodex pero ¿cuál es el contenido en JS? es una cadena y un objeto, ¿puedes agregarlo a la pregunta?